# socket.io.js not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

For some reason my node server cannot serve the route `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, I always get a 404 error.
I tried compiling different node versions (*current is 0.6.13 which also runs on server, where it actually works*).
From the app.js I get `info: socket.io started` and no error when trying to call the socket.io.js.

I try it from localhost and port 8000 and I use the express framework

This is the code from app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: true });

app.listen(8000);

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   // all other stuff here
```

Comment: Show us your code (socket.io initialization and framework initialization if you are using one).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Please check your Express version. Express recently is updated to 3.0alpha which API was changed. If 3.0 you can change your code to something likes this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

...

server.listen(8000);
```

Same issue with connect: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/500#issuecomment-4620773

Comment: Ok that sounds very close, I replaced it with your code and now I get this error when I try to start the server: `Cannot call method 'on' of undefined`. This corresponds to following code piece: `io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {`. This is just plain weird. I feel so lost.

Comment: btw I forgot to add that I actually have express 3.0alpha installed

Comment: Sorry, I write wrong code of socket.io. I updated it, please change your code again.

Comment: No problem, it has just happened to me half a day ago :)

Comment: For future reference don't forget to change `app.listen()` to `server.listen()` if you are using example snippets.

Comment: I had tried probably 15 or 20 different variations of very similar code. This is the one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is viable with Docker too. Check [this](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/60aaaeec-d582-461b-8bd6-ebe2b63dfd50) post for an live example.

Answer (score 4):

**Using with the Express 3 web framework**: ([from socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use))

*> Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach socket.io to first:*

meaning - (1) you must create a server instance:

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
```

(2) couple it with the socket.io:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(http);
```

and ONLY THEN - (3) make the server listen:

```
http.listen(8080);
```

**make sure you keep this order!**

Answer (score 1):

After installing node 0.8.1 I had the same problem.
I just deleted the node_modules map in my project folder and reinstalled express/socket.io.
After that it worked fine again with the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you, on my Ubuntu 11.10 I haven't properly set `NODE_PATH` variable, 
If you are on linux/mac try add line below to your .bashrc/.zshrc file.

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
```

Comment: I added the `node_modules` to my NODE_PATH but it still doesn't work. Too bad, it really raised my hopes. But strangely enough, when installing something via npm it says: `Checking for node path: not found`. But when echoing $NODE_PATH I get `/usr/local/lib/node:/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. I am really confused at this point.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Socket.io inside your repository:**

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

**After, config the server:**

```
   var express = require('express')
   var app     = express();
   var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
   var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

   server.listen(app.get('80')); // not 'app.listen'
```

**And inside your archive `HTML/EJS` or another you want, add:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Check if works with `Console` (Chrome/ Mozilla, etc).

**In my example I use Chrome (Ctrl + shift + I):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default port 3000 did not work for me, even though it is not in use. It fails with a 404 error for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (and no other notification or explanation). Try a different port that you're sure is not in use, and it might work for you.