# node.js: socket.io vs express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have the following server.js running:

```
module.exports = server;

var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = express.createServer();    

var port = 58000;
server.listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.use(express.static('/', __dirname + '/../public'));

server.use(express.logger());

io.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('new client connected ' + client);
    client.on('message', function(){
        console.log('client wants something');
    });
});
```

Simple express.static server for files in a /public subfolder, plus socket.io functionality. With this setup, any request for the 'socket.io.js' file fails, i.e.

```
http://localhost:58000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

returns a 404 error (file not found). Static file server works correctly. If I simply use the 'http' module instead of 'express' (commenting out express.static and express.logger lines) socket.io.js is served correctly. How can I combine both functionalities?

Answer (score 3):

Express 3.0.0 (lastest) change its API.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192084/1265207) is a question very similar to yours that delivers the response.

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

...

server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the last versions of express.js and of socket.io.js.
My side it's working great with

```
express@2.5.8 
socket.io@0.8.5 
node@0.6.5
```

Otherwise, a solution can be to call `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` after your `server.use`

Comment: express@3.0.0alpha1 may not have been a good idea... working now

Comment: Oh, in fact, there is some big troubles with express@3 for the moment, mainly on the router and middlewares, they are working on it. You should limit yourself to stable version (current is @2.5.9), if you don't plan to fork express.js