# Socket.io.js not found on Ubuntu but is on Windows

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, socket.io

I've been pulling out my hair trying to figure this problem out. I have a node.js app that works fine in windows. I zipped everything up and put it on my linux box (Ubuntu 12) and installed all of the libraries through npm, and yet I still get a 404 message saying my socket.io.js file cannot be found. I've tried various solutions such as linked to the cdn.socket.io script but that just throws a "require not found" error. My code in my html is as follows:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I've even tried `<script src="localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

and here is my server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
...
app.listen(4000);
console.log('server started');
```

This question is similar, however the answer for it is simply is an updated express semantic which shouldn't apply to my code: [socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found)

If my understanding is correct, the script path should work because when socket.io is running, it should direct that request to the right route. I don't really know what else I should look into for a fix, could it be something with the path in Ubuntu?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Just tested this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
```

Went to localhost:8000 and the 'welcome to socket.io' message showed up so I know it is running....

**paths**
node_modules: `/home/alex/node_modules/socket.io`
my node app: `/home/alex/documents/project/app.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it seemed that the reason was that something went wrong during the installation of socket.io.
Actually the only workaround I found was to make a new directory, copy all your code there and do a fresh install of the Express and socket.io modules:
npm install express socket.io
Maybe I was lucky, but it worked!

Comment: Did a fresh install on a redhat server and it worked fine. Go figure hah.