# Serving the socket.io javascript file to a client via node.js/express

Tags: node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

I'm trying to get a sample client connection working with socket.io and express (specifically, this one: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/nodejs-modules-socketio/ with some pieces from the other examples at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/app.js).

I've gotten most of the pieces set up and working - the server runs, and I can hit / to get the index.jade file to the browser. However, once that happens, it does nothing.

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express')
, stylus = require('stylus')
, nib = require('nib');

var app = express.createServer()
var io = io.listen(app);

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(stylus.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public', compile: compile }));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.set('views', __dirname);
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  function compile (str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
      .set('filename', path)
      .use(nib());
  };
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { layout: false });
});


app.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('A socket connected!');
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

index.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    link(href='/stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script
      // socket.io specific code
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
      socket.on('connect', function () {
        alert('connected');
      });
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
  body
    #chat
```

It appears that the server isn't serving /socket.io/socket.io.js (http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js yields an error). What do I need to do to get express to serve that file? I can't find that in any of the examples.

Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It appears I have this same issue - as of the newer version (3.x) of express, this example is broken: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10192084/135336

Answer (score 10):

[Using Socket.IO](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) with Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach socket.io to:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  ;
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the upgrade guides for using Express 3 with socket.io recommend passing an http.createServer to socket.io.

This works but it doesn't seem to serve the socket.io client file correctly.
With a bit of testing I found it works if you pass what is returned from app.listen to socket.io:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = app.listen(3000),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

**Note for some of the people who have replied:** it's not a file path issue. When using node + socket.io http server socket.io automatically intercepts the get call to *'/socket.io/socket.io.js'* and serves the client file for you. It doesn't actually exist in the web file structure. This functionality appeared broken when using Express 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is a 404 - you're not setting up ExpressJS to serve static files. When you request `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, it isn't finding a route, and not serving static files, so it returns back a 404.

Generally, you'd want to set up a folder that will be used to serve static files, like `public`. Inside it, place your `socket.io` folder, and inside that the `socket.io.js` file. Then, you'd add this to your `app.configure` block:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Now ExpressJS knows to serve the JS file when the request is made. You can read more about ExpressJS static configuration [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration).

**Update:**
My mistake - I see you've already set up the static server. Are your directory paths correct? Is the `socket.io` folder in your `public` folder? Without seeing your specific error, it's hard to know what the issue may be.