# where is socket.io.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mod-proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found)

I installed a simple web-chat demo:
https://github.com/sorensen/node-chat-demo

and I want to connect to it via an apache proxy server, so that instead of:

http://ip.address:3000/...

the address will be:

http://proxy.server/erel/...

This works for the static pages, for example, the address:

http://proxy.server/erel/javascripts/chat.js

correctly translates to:

http://ip.address:3000/javascripts/chat.js

However, it does not work with socket.io.js:

http://proxy.server/erel/socket.io/socket.io.js

does not translate to:

http://ip.address:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

because socket.io.js is not actually there...

so where is it?

Comment: OK, I found out that my problem was really related to Apache proxy server - I rewrote the question

Answer (score 0):

socket.io.js is not static. depending on the client capabilities, different versions are sent to the browser (e.g. for native socket support, flash sockets, jsonp)