# node.js app can't find socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I installed socket.io in the app directory (along with express) and in the `index.html` file I link to it this way:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I get a 404 on this request. I double-checked the link and it's fine. the node.js app runs on port 8080 and I have no idea why it doesn't work

UPDATE:
Apparently it is something to with Express. When not using it I don't have that problem and socket.io works fine.
This is he setup of my server file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.listen(8000);
```

and this is the front-end:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

Also, I switched the jQuery from google CDN to local and it doesn't find it too

Comment: What do you mean "it's fine" when it's not found? Is there a file at that path?

Comment: @tadman yes, the file is here, but it gives me 404...

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket.io.js not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you've made `socket.io` listening to external connections in your back-end. Basically socket.io has inside method of providing your `socket.io.js` file, so you should place your `require ('socket.io').listen(app)` before defining any routes to your app.

The correct url is :

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

as randunel said.

So, your configuration should look like this :

UPDATED for express 3.x :

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8000);

require('socket.io').listen(server);  // Your app passed to socket.io
```

Server-side

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: I updated my question to show the server file, is that what you mean?

Comment: I get a bunch of errors: `listen` method expects `http.Server` and then `io is not defined`

Comment: this is because of express 3.x i've updated the answer. This exact code work for me ;) .. try ```curl http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js``` and you should see ```  debug - served static content /socket.io.js``` in your console

Comment: could you share your code? The warning is gone, but `io` is still `undefined`... I'm going crazy here.. thanx for the help :)

Comment: Well there is no io defined since I don't need that, you can define io, by changing ```var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22453/discussion-between-drinchev-and-ilyad)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use that whole path, it does not correspond to your project's directory structure. Just use

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

By the way, make sure that socket.io is also listening on 8080, not just the other services in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your JS file in `http://localhost:8080/javascripts/socket.io.js`, basically the JavaScript directory of your `public` folder.

Comment: which js file? the server file or the socket.io?

Comment: it says nothing there about the location of the socket.io.js file. I switched to port 80 so all will be as it appears in the documentation and I still get `GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

The way is the one from randunel.

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

If you link the file directly, you can get a "Welcome to socket.io" message instead of the file.
There's also a CDN socket.io.js file available to link, but it's outdated and will not work fine on new projects, so it's not recommended.