# tutorial for Express 3.x and socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io

Is there a good starter tutorial combining socket.io and express using Express 3.x?

Actually a simple chat application would be great.

The less lines of code it uses the better.

Comment: this totorial works with Express 2.x : http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/     It would be amazing if anyone could rewrite this to Express 3.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check any 2.x tutorial and change the way to start the server as this post explains:
[socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found)

2.X.X

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(10000);
```

3.X.X

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(10000);
```

Comment: Thank you Riwels, the socket.io server starts without any error now. There is another issue : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284668/simple-express-3-x-socket-io-chat>

Comment: we got it working now: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284668/simple-express-3-x-socket-io-chat>