# Broadcast updated data to all clients connected to nodejs server over socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an application that I'm writing that needs to be able to update all connected clients whenever a client connects to a local socket server via an ajax request and updates the system. handling the request is fine but sending the response from the local socket server to socket.io to broadcast to everyone is where I'm having an issue. I'm sure it's something simple I'm looking over here but this is very new to me so I'm having problems, specifically with the asynchronous programming mindset. Below is a shortened version of what I'm trying to accomplish and where I'm faltering.

```
var express = require('express'),
    http    = require('http'),
    net     = require('net'),
    app     = express(),
    server  = http.createServer(app),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get("/execute", function (req, res) {
    // connect to local socket server
    var localSock = net.createConnection("10000","127.0.0.1");
    localSock.setEncoding('utf8');

    localSock.on('data', function(data) {
        // send returned results from local socket server to all clients
        do stuff here to data ...
        send data to all connected clients view socketio socket...
        var dataToSend = data;
        localSock.end();

    }).on('connect', function(data) {
        // send GET data to local socket server to execute
        var command = req.query["command"];
        localSock.write(command);   
});

app.get (..., function() {});

app.get (..., function() {});

server.listen('3000');

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.broadcast.send(dataToSend);
});
```

Comment: try to call `io.emit('commandExecuted',dataToSend)` after you do `.write()` to the socket server, it should emit an event to all clients connected to `socket.io` server.. the snippet looks kind of incomplete..

Comment: after I do the write command and manipulate that data in localSock.on('data', function(data) { }. I don't want to send that to the clients before that additional processing is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global socket object is referenced as `io.sockets`. Therefore, to globally broadcast, just pass data to `io.sockets.emit()` and it will be send to all clients, regardless of namespace.

The code that you posted, assuming you meant `io.sockets.on`:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.broadcast.send(dataToSend);
});
```

Is listening for any connection to any namespace, and broadcasting `dataToSend` to all clients once a connection has been established. Since your main objective is to send data to everyone, you would just leverage the global namespace, `io.sockets`, but the way it is used in your code doesn't work.

```
app.get('/execute', function (req, res) {
  var localSock = net.createConnection("10000","127.0.0.1");

  localSock.setEncoding('utf8');
  localSock.on('connect', function(data) {
    var command = req.query.command;
    localSock.write(command);   
  });
  localSock.on('data', function(data) {
    var dataToSend = data;
    localSock.end();
  });

});
```

In this part of your code, you are properly listening for `GET` requests on the path `/execute` but your socket logic isn't correct. You are writing `command` immediately on connection, which is fine, but you are assuming that the `data` event means that the stream of data has ended. Since the stream has the event `end`, you would want to collect the response with the `data` events, then finally do something with the data on `end`;

For example, if the server sent the string `This is a string that is being streamed.` and you were to use:

```
localSock.on('data', function(data) {
  var dataToSend = data;
  localSock.end();
});
```

You might only receive `This is a stri` and then prematurely close the socket with `end()`. Instead, you would want to do this:

```
var dataToSend = [];

localSock.on('data', function(data) {
  dataToSend.push(data);
});
localSock.on('end', function() {
  dataToSend = dataToSend.join('');
  io.sockets.emit(dataToSend);
});
```

Note that in this case, you don't need to use `end()` because the remove server will send its own `FIN` packet.

I'd like to ask what you're doing with `net.Socket`, because the data returned is a [`Readable Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream), which means, when you listen on the `data` event, the data may be fragments of the full response that have to be collected until the `end` event is fired. If what you're trying to do is send a message to a `socket.io` server, then you could instead use `socket.io-client`, socket.io's own client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from a very popular [webtutorial](http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/). Some changes were made in order to use Express 3.x.

here is the code of app.js:

```
 var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000);
// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

The obove code is the same code as in the webtutorial only some changes for Express 3.x were made using  the [answer of Riwels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279778/tutorial-for-express-3-x-and-socket-io#_=_) .

here is the code of index.html:

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>USERS</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```