# Cannot get /socket.io/socket.io.js on client application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

My **server** side application is hosted on `heroku`: https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com/

Relevant code looks like this:

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  console.log(err || 'listening on my very special port ' + port)
})
```

In my heroku logs this gets logged: `"listening on my very special port 28428"`

Now on my **client** application:

Currently my client application is running on port 8080

In my `index.html`:

```
<script>/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I go to `localhost:8080` I get the following errors:

```
Cannot GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

Other Attempts:

```
<script src="https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com:28428/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Cannot GET https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com:28428/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

<script src="https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Cannot GET https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And then I copied `./node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js` to `resources/js` and get this error:

```
Cannot GET http://localhost:8080/resources/js/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas?

I've used these all as references and still coming up short:

[node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426882/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found)

[Node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found express 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179827/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found-express-4-0)

[Can't get socket.io.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365044/cant-get-socket-io-js)

Comment: https://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js seems to work for me

Comment: Ohhh Thanks. I was adding a port number
<script src="http://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script> instead of <script src="http://shielded-dusk-72399.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify from where to serve your static js file. For instance, if you placed the `socket.io.js` file in your `/resources/js/` folder, add the following:

```
app.use('/resources', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'resources')))
```

Then your file will be available on `http://localhost:8080/resources/js/socket.io.js`